# When I try to run the pom.xml with Maven, it throws this error at me and I do not understand why. pom.xml -> Run Maven -> Goals -> generate-sources

Tags: java, maven, glassfish, pom.xml

I'm using Netbeans, Glassfish, and Maven, obviously, it is a Webservice using Jax-WS. This is the error log:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at

Comment: Please add complete stacktrace and describe the context.

Comment: I can't add complete stacktrace because: "It looks like your post is mostly code..." :(

Comment: Hence I said "add complete stacktrace and describe the context". Describe in text what you have done.

Comment: Do you have maven installed?

Comment: I already found where the problem was. It turns out that I had "C: / Users / Juan Jiménez" and by the accent I was throwing the error. When I deleted "Jiménez" it worked for me correctly. Thank you!

Comment: did you execute mvn command with -e and/or -X options?

Comment: @рüффп im using NeatBeans so I just run the file by click on it.